# Powershell CSV import and update IF function

Tags: powershell, if-statement, import

I have a .csv file that I wish to work with in Powershell.
The .csv has three columns

AccountNumber1, AccountNumber2, Order

The data can be in a number of variables

Now the data is non consistent, There will always be an AccountNumber2.  However If AccountNumber1 exists then this is the account number that needs to be used.

[image]

Other than the import-csv options I have no ideas on how to progress this, I wondered about if length = 0 or something around this but completely unsure.

Easy to do in excel but I would prefer not to write an excel function in as feel that its an extra layer of complexity this shouldn't really need.

```
Import-Csv -literalpath 'L:\SList.txt' -Headers AccountNumber1,AccountNumber2,CorrectAC,Order
```

Excel would simply be; `=IF(A2="",B2,A2)` obviously but how this is completed in PS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to replace empty `AccountNumber1` fields:

```
$headers = 'AccountNumber1','AccountNumber2','CorrectAC','Order'
Import-Csv -literalpath 'L:\SList.txt' -Headers $headers |
    Select-Object -Property *,@{n='AccountNumber1';e={
        if (! $_.AccountNumber1) {$_.AccountNumber2}
    }} -Exclude AccountNumber1
```

Comment: Most appreciated, seems so logical!